# API data from provider seems to get lost during Navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management, flutter-navigation, flutter-state

I am a beginner level Flutter developer trying to resolve the issue with the Navigation stack.
In the existing app:

- When user logs in to the app, login api call is shooted
- Homescreen is rendered with Navigator.popUntill method
- All the APIs in the providers get shooted and the respective tabs/screens get filled with api data.

Now, I want to include Onboarding screens before Homescreen, so I made below changes:

- Navigator.push method used to include Onboarding screens.
- After onboarding screens are over, user clicks on "To app" button
- On click of "To app" button, the login call is made again
- User is redirected to Homescreen with Navigator.popUntill method.

But now the data from providers is lost as the respective screens do not show any data. I am pretty sure that something is going wrong with the Navigation stack when I use Navigator.push method to add Onboarding screens but I do not have much expertise in Flutter to debug the issue. Need help with restoring the provider data when navigating to Onboarding screens.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cause **isn't** in a **navigation stack**. Probably you placed `Provider` widget lower than navigation (`MaterialApp`).
Try something like that or show your code for better understanding.

```
Provider(
  create: (context) => ClassThatCallsAPI(),
  child: MaterialApp(
    // Navigator placed here and any route will
    // get the same data from provider
    // and also can put some
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was making a mistake by calling api twice and pushing the route to Homescreen again over a stack instead of popping up the route to Homescreen.